# Maven Compiler plugin (3.11.0) not supported when upgraded java 17 and spring boot 3.1.4 in Jenkins Pipeline Only

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin

I have upgraded my SpringBoot project to JAVA 17 and SpringBoot version 3.1.4. Because in my project Spring Security is used  above 6. I am able to build and release the code after all upgrade in my local.

- But it failed in Jenkins Pipeline when it started building. There is no problem in local build and other testing as well.
- We are getting following error. We also upgraded the Jenkins Agent.

  ```
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:
  compile (default-compile) on project uni-dashboard-portal-external: 
  Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported
  ```
- I am using pom.xml and maven plugin.
- I am able to release the code. Able to build and test the code locally but not able to build in Jenkins.
  Below code I used in pom.xml
  I have upgraded my Springboot project to JAVA 17 and springboot version 3.1.4. Because in my project Spring Security is used  above 6. I am able build and release the code after all upgradation in my local.
  But it failed in Jenkins Pipeline when it started building. There is no problem in local build and other testing as well.

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
    <source.version>${java.version}</source.version>
</properties>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>${java.version}</release>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: With which JVM Version does your Jenkins Build run? Maybe you have selected there still the old JVM Version.

Comment: Remove the `maven.compiler.*` and `source.version` properties. Remove the `maven-compiler-plugin`, Spring Boot already ships with one. The error you get is for not having JDK17 on the build server.  If you really want to override/extend it remove the `release/target` tags from the compiler plugin, you will get those from the one managed by Spring Boot.